# Angular-UI-Router with Html5Mode refresh page issue

Tags: angularjs, html, angular-ui-router

I have an app that uses **angular-ui-router** with **html5mode(true)**. Everything seems to work fine when running and routing to other states.

My default state is *app/calendar* which is set during module.run()

But when i refresh the page while i'm currently in other routes(lets say *app/profile*) it takes me back to app/calendar.

Debugging i noticed that the $state.current is always empty after i refresh the page

```
Object {name: "", url: "^", views: null, abstract: true}
```

if only the $state.current has value i can just transistion to the current state.

Is there anything that i am missing?

Hopefully someone can help.

My **server routing** looks like

```
app.get('/:var(/|app/calendar|app/customers|app/profile|app/settings)?', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile('/app/main/main.html',{ root: '../Appt/public' });
});
```

i'm always serving the same file.

and my **front-end state configuration**

```
(
    function()
    {
        angular.module('Appt.Main').config(['$stateProvider','$locationProvider',function($stateProvider,$locationProvider)
        {
            $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

            var calendar = {
                    name: 'calendar',
                    url: 'app/calendar',
                    controller: 'Appt.Main.CalendarController',
                    controllerAs: 'calendar',
                    templateUrl: '/app/main/calendar/calendar.html'
                },
                customers = {
                    name: 'customers',
                    url: 'app/customers',
                    controller : 'Appt.Main.CustomersController',
                    controllerAs : 'customers',
                    templateUrl : '/app/main/customers/customers.html'
                },
                profile = {
                    name: 'profile',
                    url: 'app/profile',
                    controller : 'Appt.Main.ProfileController',
                    controllerAs : 'profile',
                    templateUrl : '/app/main/profile/profile.html'
                },
                settings = {
                    name: 'settings',
                    url: 'app/settings',
                    controller : 'Appt.Main.SettingsController',
                    controllerAs : 'settings',
                    templateUrl : '/app/main/settings/settings.html'
                };


            $stateProvider.state(calendar);
            $stateProvider.state(customers);
            $stateProvider.state(profile);
            $stateProvider.state(settings);

        }]);

    }
)();
```

My module.run

```
(
    function()
    {
        'use strict';

        angular.module('Appt.Main',['ngRoute','ui.router','Appt.Directives'])
            .run(['$state','$stateParams', function ($state,$stateParams) {
                console.log('Appt.Main is now running')


                console.log($state.current);
                console.log($stateParams);

                $state.transitionTo('calendar');


            }])
    }
)();
```

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure if this is going to solve your problem, but I had a very similar problem. First thing I had to do to use `html5mode` was to use a rewrite property so the app would reload from the index file when i refresh the page, no matter what `$state` I'm. This is the code I´m using, but it may be different, depending on the serverside you are using.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    #RewriteBase /relative/web/path/

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^(.+) - [PT,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
    RewriteRule ^(.*) index.html

    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization}  !^$
    RewriteRule .* - [E=REMOTE_USER:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

You can read more here, in the [docs from ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode)

Also, you'd better set a base or not use a base for your app.

You either insert `<base href="/" >`inside your head tag (or other base folder, depending on your structure).

Or you can use:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
    enabled: true,
    requireBase: false
});
```

So you don't have to use a base.

Also, you don't need a `.run` to define a default state, `ui-router` can do it with `$urlRouterProvider.when` or `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise`
You can [read more in the docs](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#urlrouterprovider-1)

Since I'm new user to Angular, this is just what i did to solve my problem, which was very similar to yours. Hope it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and I fixed it by adding this:

```
app.config(..., $urlMatcherFactoryProvider) {
    $urlMatcherFactoryProvider.strictMode(false);
});
```

This is because my route was adding a trailing slash `/` at the end of the paths and `$stateProvider` was not recognizing the URL, thus taking me back to the home state.