# AngularJs Page Refresh Gives 404 Page not found on server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

this routing working fine on `loaclhost`. but when I deploy my application on server and refresh any page it shows error of 404 error page not found.
    below is my routing

```
$routeProvider
           .when("/", {
               templateUrl: "/views/login.cshtml"

           })
            .when("/Login", {
                templateUrl: "/Views/login.cshtml"

            })
            .when("/adminlogin", {
                templateUrl: "/views/login.cshtml"

            })
            .when("/Register", {
                templateUrl: "/Views/Register.cshtml"
            })


            .when("/blue", {
                templateUrl: "blue.htm"
            }).otherwise('/', {
                redirectTo: '/'
            });
        $locationProvider
          .html5Mode(true)
```

anyone knows the solution kindly share.

Comment: i think its due to the `html5mode(true)`, it replaces '/#!/' by '/', but at the time of refresh you would have to handle that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32009845/5633939 check this

Comment: @the_mishra not working

Answer (score 0):

Maybe , U need rewrite route mapping on server side and return index page

```
   routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{*url}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
            );
```